# Definition of differential forms using the exterior algbera

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

### Background

I am trying to understand the following way of introducing differential k-forms.

> [image]

We started with the exterior algebra and defined $\Lambda^{k}V:=(\Lambda_{k}V)^{*}=(V^{\otimes k}/<\otimes v>)^{*}$. I think I am more or less fine with the extiror algebra. Then there is the following:

> [image]

### My Question

- How is $Y^{0}=(\Lambda_{k}V)^{*}$? Isn't $\Lambda_{k}V)$ a quotient of a of $V^{\otimes k}$? So how can this be a subset of $V^{\otimes k}$? My guess is that the argument goes like:
  first show $\{\text{functionals that vanish on} <\otimes^{k} v>\}\simeq Alt^{k}V$ , then $(\Lambda_{k}V)^{*}\simeq \{\text{functionals that vanish on} <\otimes^{k} v>\}$. So erverything is equal only up to isomorphism.
- I don't get the last line. Isn't an element of $(\Lambda_{k}V)^{*}$ a map, say $\phi :\Lambda_{k}V\to\mathbb{R},v_{1}\wedge ...\wedge v_{k}\mapsto\phi(v_{1}\wedge ...\wedge v_{k})$. What I found on the internet is that $Alt^{k}V\simeq (\Lambda_{k}V)^{*}$, which would make a lot more sense to me.
- According to the definition of $\Lambda_{k}V$ I would say that $\omega_{p}$ is a map that "eats" k-vectors, but then there is the following statement:

> [image]

But there is also the following:

> [image]

I have to say I am pretty confused about what follows right from the definition and what not.

- How is the $\omega_{p}(X_{1},...,X_{k})=\omega(X_{1}\wedge...\wedge X_{k})$ justified? If we would start with $\omega(X_{1},...,X_{k})$ I would say that by the universal property there is a linear function $\omega$ such that.... . But since we start off with $\omega(X_{1}\wedge...\wedge X_{k})$ how do I know that there is a k-linear alternating form that conicides with $\omega(X_{1}\wedge...\wedge X_{k})$? Does $\beta(X_{1},...,X_{n}):=\omega(X_{1}\wedge...\wedge X_{k})$ do the job?

I hope the questions make at least a bit sense. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: I think the lecture notes are more or less based on Boothby's book.

Comment: I find the notation to be confusing. If you define $\bigwedge^kV^*$ to be the space of antisymmetric multilinear functions of $V$ and therefore a subspace of $V^{\otimes k}$. then indeed $\bigwedge^kV$ is a quotient space. However, I prefer to avoid using $\bigwedge^kV$ at all.  I also don't understand the notation for differential forms. I would define $\Omega^kM$ as the space of sections of $\bigwedge^kT^*M$, not $\bigwedge^kT_*M$.

Comment: Are you refering to what I wrote or the excerpts from the notes? The notes actually say that most books avoid it because it may be more difficult. Do you know a book that takes this approach? I guess I need to understand it as it is part of the lecture notes.

Comment: I'm referring to the excerpts.

Comment: The point, referring to your comment after Definition B.3.1 is that you should not view $\bigwedge^kV$ (which I would write as $\bigwedge^kV^*$) as the dual to $\bigwedge_kV$ (which I would write as $\bigwedge^kV$). That leads only to a lot of confusiong. You can always use only exterior multlinear functions and avoid exterior products of vectors. I recommend doing so.

Comment: Okay I see. I hope that I'll be able to make sense of it.

Comment: @Deane Is what is mentioned in the last excerpt meant to mean that we can define an alternating k-linear map through $\omega_{p}(X_{1},...,X_{k}):=\omega(X_{1}\wedge...\wedge X_{k})$. Isn’t that exactly how one shows that there is an isomorphism between $Alt^{k}V$ and $(\Lambda_{k})^{*}$? I had look at Tu’s differential geometry book. He uses the exterior algebra too. Is his approach along the lines of your approach? In case you know/have the book.

Comment: Could you tell me which book by Tu and what section in the book you're referring to? I just skimmed through Chapter 3 of Introduction of Manifolds, and it appears to me that he is very careful to talk about the exterior algebra of $V^*$ only and never of $V$ itself. I also didn't see any discussion about the duality between $\bigwedge^kV^*$ and $\bigwedge^kV^*$ (using my notation).

Comment: It is this one https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783319550824

Comment: In Chapter 19 he talks about the exterior algebra.

Comment: Are you trying to learn the basics of differential forms or are you way ahead of that and trying to read the book after section 19? The book assumes you already know about differential forms, and this is presented in Tu's book Introduction to Manifolds. Section 19 is, I believe, laying groundwork for the last chapter of the book, which is about characteristic classes. The situation there is more elaborate than for differential forms per se.

Comment: Actually I am just trying to learn the basics, but since the lecture notes talk about all of what is in chapter 19 I guess I have to have at least an idea of those concepts. Furthermore Riemannian geometry is also part of the lecture.

Comment: You definitely do not need to know section 19 to use differential forms in Riemannian geometry. Do the lecture notes refer specifically to section 19 of Tu's book? If not, I recommend reading the section on diffferential forms in his manifolds book. Are these lecture notes publicly available?

Comment: No not at all, but I find it a bit difficult to understand the concepts from the notes. Here is the link https://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/geometrie/Lehre/WS19/DGII/dg2.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I'll write a comment in the answer section.

Comment: Basically, the answer to your last question is yes. Does that not answer all of the earlier questions?

Comment: Yes, I guess it does. But thank you very much for your help anyway! I really appreciate it.